# How to select multiple images using intents in kotlin

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin

I tried some codes. But i could not get the right solution. Can someone help?

Below is the code:

```
private var context: Context? = null
var PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1
lateinit var imagePath: String
var imagesPathList: MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()
```

Comment: `I tried some codes.` To do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Uri for each file when using `startActivityForResult` from an activity class:

```
private fun pickImageMultiple() {
    intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
        type = "image/*"
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
        // use clipData
        data?.clipData ...
    }
}
```

You can get the paths for each file from the Uris with `getPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below codes -

```
val intent = Intent();
intent.setType("image/*")
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pick Photos"), 101)
```